# Copy and pasting my xib file and keeping References

Tags: xcode, ios-universal-app

So I've finished my Universal App for the Apple Store. All the code works I make all the views and references using my iPhone xib file. However, my iPad xib file is blank. So normally I would just copy and paste all the views from my iPhone xib file to the iPad file and resize each view along with its subviews, however, doing this does not copy any references. So I have to manually link each button all over again. Not a big deal, but the app I just made has like 200 buttons and I don't really want to have to link everything again. I was hoping someone here knows how to keep all the references?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to copy and paste the view from one xib file to another while keeping all the IBOutlet and IBAction connections. But one thing you could do is go to File->Duplicate in the Xcode toolbar, and duplicate your xib file. That will create a new xib file with the same views and all of the connections intact.